# SQL query Structure Statement

Tags: sql

I need some help with a SQL query.  Lets say I have data that looks like so;

```
UserID Department Team
------ ---------- ----
ST44   Media      grean
GB56   Dev        blue
HH32   Vendor     black
TH89   Vendor     black
LK98   Dev        blue
LK98   Media      green
```

I need a SQL statement that runs against a user such as WHERE user = "LK98" and it would display;

```
UserID Department Team
------ ---------- ----
LK98   Dev        blue
LK98   Media      green
```

but I also want to see who else is in that department. So for an example, I search for User1, it will show me that User1 is in A, B and C departments and also show me that User2 is in departments A and B and User3 is in department C.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?   Maybe a SQL tutorial would help you get started:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: What have you already tried? What is your RDBMS (SQL Flavor)? Are you proficient with `JOIN`s and/or `sub-queries`?

Comment: I believe the part he is having difficulty with is what is under the second result set. Not with showing the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes the issue.

```
select t.userid, t.department, t.Team
from   (
       select department
       from myTable
       where userid = 'LK98'
       ) d
join   myTable t
       on t.department = d.department
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USERID = 'LK98'

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. The OP wants the result to include other users that are in the requested user's department(s).